# x86 printer driver for sharing hp laserjet 1300 pcl5 printer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, print-drivers

I have an HP LaserJet 1300 PCL 5 printer attached to a 64bit Windows 7 PC.  I am trying to print share from a Windows XP laptop.  I need the x86 print driver to install on the Windows 7 machine.  Can't seem to find this driver.

Joel and Callen, neither one of the links had the x86 driver on them or they didn't work. The XP laptop appears to send the print job to the printer over the network. but never reaches the Windows 7 machine or the 1300 pcl5 printer. Is there a driver name or file name that needs to be there to install. The message I get when trying to install the x86 driver from Printer Properties is: "Installation of the UPD x86 (32 bit) driver cannot install on an x64 operating system. Please obtain x64 release of this driver." Hope I wasn't to confusing.

Thanks... Ken

Comment: Have you tried installing the UPD (Universal Print Driver) from http://h20331.www2.hp.com/hpsub/cache/343033-0-0-225-121.html?jumpid=ex_r2845_go/upd

Answer (score 2):

HP's Universal Print Driver usually works like a charm in this situation. Heres a link for the download for the Windows 7 x86 driver:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=503519&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=503548&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4062

You may need to manually install the driver with the '.inf' file that comes with this driver.